# Can the overhead of rwlock is higher than the overhead of mutex?

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, rwlock

I implemented a `sorted linked list` as two versions. The first one is using single `mutex` for the entire list and the second one uses single `rwlock` for the entire list.

I ran half of the operations as `Member` and the other half made of `Insert(0.25)` and `Delete(0.25)` operations. I plotted the time against a number of threads and in this case was not as expected that the time for `rwlock` was higher than `mutex`.

How can this happen? When there are more than 90% Member operations then `rwlocks` were better as expected.

Comment: Your qeustion belongs elsewhere in the SO universe. Select your planet [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites). When migrated... post also some minimal code as test example.

Comment: "Can the overhead of rwlock is higher than the overhead of mutex?" - Yes, it can. `rwlock` implements more complex constraints than a simple `mutex`, so it may consume more memory. Not sure what is "I run half of the operations as `Member`", but inserting and deleting elements from the list are mutation operations, and they are run exclusively both with `mutex` and with `rwlock`. Why do you expect `rwlock` to show better results in that case?

Comment: @Tsyvarev could you please look into the plots [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/510038/can-the-overhead-of-rwlock-is-higher-than-the-overhead-of-mutex) and explain the situation.

Comment: Hm, I am not sure why the first commenter suggests to ask the question on other Stack Exchange site. From my understanding, the question is definitely a programming one and belongs to Stack Overflow. You suggest to look into plots, but you still don't describe what "operations as `Member`" mean. Please, update your question post with **more details**.

Comment: `Member` means searching the list for a given integer by traversing the list starting from the first node. `Delete` and `Insert` operations do the same traversing and do delete the node if found or insert a new node to the correct position in sorted list.